# Visitor Registration and tracking in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

for a very small business im trying to make an excel log of visitors. The thing is i want to register some permanent information like Name, ID,address, phone number to basically register a visitor, then somehow on another sheet maybe add data that is specific per visit, like date,Body temperature measured,and a few other items.

if i try to do it in 1 table on 1 sheet, i would have to copy paste the same information that does not change often, like address, id, phone every time. this is why i would like to split it in 2 tables, 1 for registering the more permanent stuff and 1 sheet for the specific visit. So 1 Visitor can be registered only once in the Registration Sheet, but can have multiple visit in the other Sheet.

Is there a way that i can better organize this?

- Like for excel to auto complete the name as i type (from the names already registered)
- a way to see that the Visitor is already registered
- any way to link the data on the registration sheet to the second sheet? because i cannot hyperlink to a specific cell...

Any help to organize this will be much appreciated.
EDIT: here is the file i'm using:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=34680980172101379617

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data along with expected outputs, will help us to understand your need to fix it !

Comment: Please provide the sample about your problem.

Comment: Here is a link of the excel file
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=34680980172101379617